# java static import protected fields visibility

Tags: java

Given two classes `A` and `B`, `A` in package `a` and `B` in package `b`, to import class `B` into `A`, the class `B` must **not** be package private. Fair enough, what about importing static members of class `B` ? Let's clarify with a simple example :

```
package b;

public class B
{
    protected static final int VALUE = 1;
}
```

From here, we can statically import `B.VALUE` into `A` only if `A` extends `B`.

```
package a;

import b.B;
import static b.B.VALUE;

class A extends B
{
    int getValue()
    {
        return VALUE;
    }
}

class C
{

}
```

Here, what about class `C`, does it have access to the static field `B.VALUE` even though it does not extend class `B` ?

Comment: "Does it have access ?" can't you just try ? I'll take you a second to know

Comment: @azro I am not in front of my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: NO

There is nice explanation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

[image]

Particularly you would be interested in this table. You can see that `protected` modifier make field to be visible for classes in same package and classes extending this class.

Answer (score 0):

*Does it have access to the static field B.VALUE* : **no**

---

`protected` can be access from :

- within the class itself;
- within the package;
- from a subclass,

But `C` is *none* of that.

---

```
            | Class | Package | Subclass | Subclass | World
            |       |         |(same pkg)|(diff pkg)| 
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+——————————+————————
public      |   +   |    +    |    +     |     +    |   +     
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+——————————+————————
protected   |   +   |    +    |    +     |     +    |   -     
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+——————————+————————
no modifier |   +   |    +    |    +     |     -    |    -
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+——————————+————————
private     |   +   |    -    |    -     |     -    |    - 

+ : accessible
- : not accessible
```

Details can found : [*here from the Docs*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)